# Eclipse Aptana 3 - No syntax highlighting (editor code in black & white)

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting, aptana3

I've installed Aptana Studio 3.7.2 standalone for Mac (from downloaded .dmg). I needed to modify config.ini to make it launch (error after selecting the workspace) on OSX Mojave 10.14.4 with Java 12.0.1 selected with jenv.

Now all works fine, excepted the syntax highlighting. All texts are black on white (Javascript and Html).

File associations (Preferences > General > Editors > File Associaitons) seems to be OK (the Outline view works fine and detect objects). I've tried to change the theme, but nothing happend.
I'm surprized that in Preferences > Aptana Studio > Theme, there is nothing in Element list.

Thanks for help

[image: screenshot of editor window]

Comment: Right-click on the file and from its Open With menu, make sure that you're opening the editor you're expecting to open.

Comment: Yes, I opened my JS files with "JavaScript Source Editor", which seems to be the good one because it is the only one that fill the Outline window..